# Javascript Popup and Class instead of ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been using a simple script to pop up a hidden `div`, and an absolute `hyperlink` in behind as a "failsafe" way for the user to close the popup. Now that I want to have multiple "pop ups" on the same page, I need to adjust so that I'm not targeting by `ID`. `getElementsbyClassName` does not seem to be working.

My current **HTML** code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonOne').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Button One</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonTwo').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Button Two</a>

<div id="buttonOne" class="white_content"><a class="closeWindow" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonOne').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">CLOSE</a>
                    <p>BUTTON ONE CONTENT</p>
</div>

<div id="buttonTwo" class="white_content"><a class="closeWindow" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonOne').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">CLOSE</a>
                    <p>BUTTON TWO CONTENT</p>
</div>

<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('buttonOne').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"></a></div>
```

And some **CSS**:

```
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.black_overlay a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    cursor:unset;
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 12%;
    left: 12%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

So the pop-up triggers/buttons work fine, because I can connect each button to its respective content `window` with a unique ID. But the div at the bottom (#fade) is what goes behind the window and fills the background with a semi-transparent overlay. I liked having a giant link there that closed the window whenever you clicked outside the content window. Since it needs to target the current open div container by ID, I'm at a loss.

I tried replacing the link in there with `document.getElementsbyClassName` and giving all of the windows the same class, but I get an `undefined` error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nice one putting all the necessary markup and CSS right there in the question. You'd be surprised how often that isn't done -- and it was key to getting a quick answer in this case. All I had to do was drop your code into a Stack Snippet, look around, and tweak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *minimal change* solution is to track the active button using a global variable, like this (the global is `activeButton`, code changes are in the  `onclick` attributes for the `a` tags and the `#fade` tag, and there's a bit of JavaScript declaring the variable):

```js
var activeButton;
```

```css
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.black_overlay a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    cursor:unset;
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 12%;
    left: 12%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="activeButton = document.getElementById('buttonOne'); activeButton.style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Button One</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="activeButton = document.getElementById('buttonTwo'); activeButton.style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Button Two</a>

<div id="buttonOne" class="white_content"><a class="closeWindow" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonOne').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">CLOSE</a>
                    <p>BUTTON ONE CONTENT</p>
</div>

<div id="buttonTwo" class="white_content"><a class="closeWindow" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonOne').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">CLOSE</a>
                    <p>BUTTON TWO CONTENT</p>
</div>

<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (activeButton) { activeButton.style.display='none';} activeButton = undefined;document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"></a></div>
```

I would **strongly** suggest moving all of that JavaScript out of `onclick=...` attributes and into functions, though, not least because it would allow a lot less code duplication.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look. Your suggestion is working perfectly. I notice now that I even mucked up my example code when trying to edit it to make it anonymous... so thanks for still making sense of it. Regarding your suggestion about creating a function to eliminate redundant code, is it bad form to ask for an example of how I would go about that?

Comment: @NathanS you can just add the .onclick method or .addEventListener('click', function(){}); Inside of your javscript here is a link to w3schools so you can check it out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: @NathanS: Not necessarily, no. I'm afraid I'm overdue for my bed, though. :-) Glad this helped! Look into `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` on IE8 and earlier).